# How to combine XML element with the same id using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an issue combining XML elements. The follwoing xml has the duplicate value (T804), how can I combine them into one T804 record in  under  record using XSLT.

Before:

```
<OBR>
<OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>IL</OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>
<OBX>
<OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T084</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
<OBX_5_1_Lbr_No></OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
<OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>HIGH</OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
<OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx></OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
<OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>1.003-1.035</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
</OBX>
<OBX>
<OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T084</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
<OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>1.038</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
<OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
<OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx></OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
<OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>1.003-1.035</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
</OBX>
<OBX>
<OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T086</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
<OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
<OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
<OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
<OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-9</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
</OBX>
<OBX>
<OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T087</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
<OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
<OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
<OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
<OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-4</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
</OBX>
</ORB>
```

After - Combining two T084 records into one.

```
<OBR>
<OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>IL</OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>
<OBX>
<OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T084</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
<OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>1.038</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
<OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>HIGH</OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
<OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx></OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
<OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>1.003-1.035</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
<OBX>
<OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T086</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
<OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
<OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
<OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
<OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-9</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
</OBX>
<OBX>
<OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T087</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
<OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
<OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
<OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
<OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-4</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
</OBX>
</ORB>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kOrderByCd" match="OBX"
  use="OBX_3_Ltt_Cd"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "OBX[generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kOrderByCd', OBX_3_Ltt_Cd)[1])
      and
       key('kOrderByCd', OBX_3_Ltt_Cd)[2]
       ]">
  <OBX>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"/>
  </OBX>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
  "OBX[not(generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kOrderByCd', OBX_3_Ltt_Cd)[1])
           )
       ]"/>

 <xsl:template match="OBX/*" mode="inGroup">
  <xsl:variable name="vNonEmpty" select=
   "key('kOrderByCd', ../OBX_3_Ltt_Cd)
            /*[name() = name(current())
             and
               text()
              ]"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "$vNonEmpty[1]| self::*[not($vNonEmpty)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<OBR>
    <OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>IL</OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>
    <OBX>
        <OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T084</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
        <OBX_5_1_Lbr_No></OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
        <OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>HIGH</OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
        <OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx></OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
        <OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>1.003-1.035</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T084</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
        <OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>1.038</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
        <OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
        <OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx></OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
        <OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>1.003-1.035</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T086</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
        <OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
        <OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
        <OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
        <OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-9</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T087</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
        <OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
        <OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx></OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
        <OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
        <OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-4</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
    </OBX>
</OBR>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<OBR>
   <OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>IL</OBR_31_Lab_Ins_Typ_Id>
   <OBX>
      <OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T084</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
      <OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>1.038</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
      <OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>HIGH</OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx>
      <OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx/>
      <OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>1.003-1.035</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
   </OBX>
   <OBX>
      <OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T086</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
      <OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
      <OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx/>
      <OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
      <OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-9</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
   </OBX>
   <OBX>
      <OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>T087</OBX_3_Ltt_Cd>
      <OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>0</OBX_5_1_Lbr_No>
      <OBX_5_2_Lbr_Tx/>
      <OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>HPF</OBX_6_Lbr_Unt_Tx>
      <OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>0-4</OBX_7_Lbr_Rng_Tx>
   </OBX>
</OBR>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Muenchian grouping.
2. Use and override of the identity rule.
3. Use of keys.